# What Kind of Spam is This? Testing Blog Comment Limits

Tags: spam-prevention, blogging

I received this comment on one of my blogs today (on blogger.com):

> Easily I agree but I about the post
>   should acquire more info then it has.

It's the third in a series. Before there was:

> I will not acquiesce in on it. I over
>   precise post. Expressly the title
>   attracted me to be familiar with the
>   sound story.

and before that

> Your blog keeps getting better and
>   better! Your older articles are not as
>   good as newer ones you have a lot more
>   creativity and originality now keep it
>   up!

It is obviously computer-generated (well, not this last one). The comments are from Anonymous, so they're not trying to legitimate a user on Blogger. Is this a spam attack? What might its goal be? Or are they just testing my blog to see if I reject or not? Does this kind of "attack" have a name?

Comment: Are you sure this is all? Maybe the Blogger software removed the links from the text, and did the original post link to other sites?

Comment: Here is today's world: you can't even trust compliments, they're related to spam as well ;)

Comment: @Gnoupi, I never trust compliments that don't say anything SPECIFIC at all. On my blog, when there have been compliments, they've talked about WHAT they were complimenting. "Meet the new boss, same as the old boss..."

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem, yes, you may be right. I'll have to try spamming myself to see what it filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the intention is to be whitelisted on the spam list. You could expect to receive spam from the same IP within a few weeks.

I, too, receive spam like this on a regular basis. It is rather frustrating, as it is confusing my Naive Bayes spam classifier: the text of the message itself is not spam.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. @Yar, please keep us posted here!

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. @Arjan van Bentem, I will keep you posted, but as I reject those messages, I think they will stop. I've noticed the same thing with my catch-all on my google-apps domains, too. Flurries of activities followed by nothing.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption has always been that this checks for the level of moderation in your comments. If you leave a clearly computer-generated post like this online, you're probably not heavily moderating your comments, and a quick Google search would allow the spammer to find you again to post some real spam.

Comment: Right, but then: why not just post the real spam in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I receive many similar comments on my blog, is the **Site** field of comments filled with external sites (of spammers)?

That's probably a way to let some visitors click on their site.

Comment: As far as I know, I've left all I know about the comments. But as I said somewhere above, I'll have to try spamming myself to see what hapens.

Answer (score 1):

You're not the only one to suffer from this.

Googling for these texts has shown only a few results for the first two.
But the last one shows **115,000 results** !!

It might be that the first two were only test-runs leading up to the third.
From the translated ones I would guess that the source is in the far-east, probably China.

Comment: +1 but not for the China part, could be from anyplace non-English. But: I posted them in order from most to least-recent. I think they were trying native, and then less native texts to see how permissive the site is... or something? Anyway, nice going on googling the phrases!